# Out of Scope Error when Testing Function for Perfect Hash

Tags: c++

I am trying to test one of the functions of my Hashing project. This function's goal is to create an index for a string from a list of 1000 strings. It is supposed to add up the ASCII values for every character in a string, multiply it by a random number ( int c) and modulo it by a prime number ( int prime1) to find the index in the hash. I am trying to test this code with the string "hi", but whenever I am doing this I keep getting a function is out of scope error. I don't understand why since the main function is just under the function it is trying to test.

This is my class

```
 //using namespace std;
 #ifndef HASH_H
 #define HASH_H

 class hash{

 // Public Member functions
 public:
 hash(); // Constructor
 int  CreateG(const std::string city);
 int  HashFunction(std::string city); // the declaration of the hash function for the primary hash

 // Private member functions
 private:


 // Protected Member functions
 protected:

 }
 #endif
```

This is my .cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Hash.h"

//using namespace std;

int  hash::HashFunction(std::string city){ // the declaration of the hash function for the primary hash


} 

int hash::CreateG(const std::string city){ // creates g(str) to use in the universal hash function 

    int prime1 = 16890581;
    int c = rand()%10; // This is the random number c to use when finding g 
    int g = 0; // initial value of g

    int x=0; // This is the sum of all the ascii values

    // Create a for loop, to iterate from 1 to 1000 (1000 because that this how many cities are in the input file)
    for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++){
        for( int t = 1; i < city.length(); t++ ) // for loop that runs through the string
        {
            char ch=city.at(i);
            int x=x+(int)ch; // This should be the running summation of the ascii values of the chars of the strings
        }
    }

    g = (x*c)%prime1;

    std::cout<<g;
    return g; // returns the value of 
}    



int main(){
    std:: string test = "hi";
    std::cout<<CreateG(test);
}
```

This is my error

```
   /home/ec2-user/environment/.c9/Project4/Hash.cpp:53:31: error: 
   ‘CreateG’ was not declared in this scope
    std::cout<<CreateG(test);
                           ^
```

Comment: This is a C++ syntax (compiler) problem. The compiler error is not related to hashing. I didn't try, but I would expect "hash()" somewhere in the main method.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateG` is a method of the `hash` class, not an independent function.

You have to instantiate an `hash` to use it.

```
int main(){
    std:: string test = "hi";
    hash h;
    std::cout<<h.CreateG(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Federico said: `CreateG` is a non-static member function, but you tried to use it like a non-member function. (Review *classes* in your C++ book.)

Also:

```
int x=x+(int)ch; // This should be the running summation of the ascii values of the chars of the strings
```

It can't be a running summation, because you redeclared a new, local `x` (and are thus also using an uninitialised value on the RHS).

Remove the `int` to assign to the existing `x` instead.